# Seam Form Variables

Tags: java, forms, variables, session, seam

Why are variables accessible in one part of an application not accessible in another part? I have a form with many input such as:

```
<h:inputText styleClass="text autocomplete" id="eventName"
                required="true"
                value="#{cvEvent.eventName}"/>
```

The variable cvEvent is declared in a EventManager class as such:

```
@In(required=false,scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Out(required=false,scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
private Event cvEvent;
```

The form is 'submitted' like this:

```
<h:commandLink id="cmdConfirmEvent" styleClass="continue"
                    action="#{eventManager.confirmNewEvent}">
</h:commandLink>
```

Within that method, eventManager.confirmedNewEvent, I can access the cvEvent variables thusly:

```
System.out.println("confirmNewEvent: " +  cvEvent.getEventName());
```

That all makes perfect sense to me. What I don't understand is why this doesn't work when I copy the form to a different page. I get:

```
WARNING: /home/Test3.xhtml @113,36 value="#{cvEvent.eventName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'cvEvent' resolved to null

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /home/Test3.xhtml @113,36 value="#{cvEvent.eventName}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'cvEvent' resolved to null
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening or where the 'scope' of the cvEvent variable is configured. Why would this work in one place and not another?

Comment: When you open the other page is the conversation still active?

Comment: How does one check if the conversation is still active?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `coversationId` or `cId` parameter in the url? this will usually indicate the current active conversation ID, or you can just call 'Conversation.instance().getId()' in your backing bean to get the current conversation ID

If you are not in an active conversation, or it is not being propagated from one page to another (the conversation ID is changing) then the `cvEvent` variable will be lost, since it lives in the CONVERSATION scope

You can change `ScopeType.CONVERSATION` to `SESSION` as an easy fix or read up on 'seam conversation propagation' keep the variable alive across redirects